# how to convert text file data to python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have seen quite a few questions like this however none like mine specific separation of items with newlines.

text file:

```
John
City: New york
Job: surgeon
Happy: no

Terry
City: Miami
House: Yes
Job: nurse
Married: No

Joe
City: LA
Married: No
Job: None
```

Dictionary should have separate items which are determined by the blank line in the text document, and the format stays the same like= 'key': 'value' but there isnt a predetermined set amount per item of the dict. could be 4 items like joe or three like john.

So far i have:

```
with open(file.txt) as file:
    id = {}
    for line in file:
        if line is not '\n'
            k,v = line.strip().split(': ', 1)
            id[k] = v.strip()
            
print(id)
```

I know this is incorrect and the previous quides have been no help when dealing with newlines.

I expect it to look like:

```
{
    "John": {
        "City": "new york",
        "Job": "surgeon",
        "Happy": "no"
    }, 
    "Terry": {
        "City": "Miami",
        "House": "Yes",
        "Job": "nurse",
        "Married": "No"
    },   
    "Joe": {
        "City": "LA",
        "Married": "No",
        "Job": "None"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
text = """\
John
City: New york
Job: surgeon
Happy: no

Terry
City: Miami
House: Yes
Job: nurse
Married: No

Joe
City: LA
Married: No
Job: None"""

out = {}
for group in text.split("\n\n"):
    lines = group.split("\n")
    out[lines[0]] = dict(l.split(": ") for l in lines[1:])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "John": {"City": "New york", "Job": "surgeon", "Happy": "no"},
    "Terry": {"City": "Miami", "House": "Yes", "Job": "nurse", "Married": "No"},
    "Joe": {"City": "LA", "Married": "No", "Job": "None"},
}
```

---

EDIT: To read the `text` from a file:

```py
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    text = f_in.read().strip()

out = {}
for group in text.split("\n\n"):
    lines = group.split("\n")
    out[lines[0]] = dict(l.split(": ") for l in lines[1:])

print(out)
```

---

EDIT 2:

If your file contains:

```
City: New york
Job: surgeon
Happy: no

City: Miami
House: Yes
Job: nurse
Married: No

City: LA
Married: No
Job: None
```

then:

```py
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    text = f_in.read().strip()

out = []
for group in text.split("\n\n"):
    lines = group.split("\n")
    out.append(dict(l.split(": ") for l in lines))

print(out)
```

prints:

```py
[
    {"City": "New york", "Job": "surgeon", "Happy": "no"},
    {"City": "Miami", "House": "Yes", "Job": "nurse", "Married": "No"},
    {"City": "LA", "Married": "No", "Job": "None"},
]
```

Comment: Sorry im still new to python, for text file would i write `for group in f.split` after `with open(filename) as f`?

Comment: @DarkSand I've updated my answer about how to read the `text` from a file.

Comment: Can you explain what `out[lines[0]] = dict(l.split(": ") for l in lines[1:])` does? I dont understand what the last part does.

Comment: @DarkSand `l.split(": ") for l in lines[1:]` will iterate over `lines` (skipping the first index, hence `[1:]`) and each line I split according the `: ` string. This will create a list of two elements (key and value). From these lists I create the final sub-dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Last question: In the case i remove the names and just leave it as the key:value pairs, how can i replace the title of the item "John" with the value "surgeon". So the item reads `"surgeon": {"City": "New york", "Job": "surgeon", "Happy": "no"}` for all items? Basically changing the name of person to the job title and keeping the job keyvalue in the item

Comment: @DarkSand What should happend if you have two `surgeon`s in your text file? The dictionary could have only unique keys.

Comment: True, I didnt not think. How about If the text file has no name and is just keyvalue pairs seperated by newlines? How would I edit your code to show mutliple dictionary items with different data in each one? example output:  {"City": "New york", "Job": "surgeon", "Happy": "no"},
    {"City": "Miami", "House": "Yes", "Job": "nurse", "Married": "No"},
    {"City": "LA", "Married": "No", "Job": "None"}}